# Print deduced template arguments at compile time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc, c++17

How to print automatically deduced template arguments at compile time?

```
std::pair x(1, 2.0);
```

In the above example the type of *x* is *std::pair<int, double>*. Is there a way to print the deduced type of *x* at compile time, e.g. as *std::pair<int, double>* or in some other readable form?

Edit. I am using a library (DPC++) that relies on C++ 17 automatic template argument deduction. Sometimes it is difficult to guess how template argument were deduces.

Comment: What do you mean by "print"? Do you mean that you want to get a string that names the full type of `x`?

Comment: By "print"  I mean compiler message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one (admittedly roundabout and verbose) approach:

```
#include <utility>

template <class T>
struct type_reader {
    type_reader() {
        int x{0};
        if (x = 1) {} // trigger deliberate warning
    }
};

int main() {
    std::pair x(1, 2.0);
    type_reader<decltype(x)> t;
}
```

Depending on your compiler and settings, you can get a warning like

```
<source>:7:19: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
        if (x = 1) {} // trigger deliberate warning
<source>:13:34: note: in instantiation of member function 'type_reader<std::pair<int, double>>::type_reader' requested here
    type_reader<decltype(x)> t;
```

and you can see the type `std::pair<int, double>>` in that mess if you squint.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you're asking two different and independent questions.

1. given an object obtained from CTAD, how obtain the deduced exact type of the object.

For this question the answer is simple: it's a work for `decltype()`, that permit something as

```
std::pair x{1, 2.0};

decltype(x) y{2, 3.0};  // y is std::pair<int, double>

static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(x), std::pair<int, double>> );
static_assert( std::is_same_v<decltype(y), std::pair<int, double>> );
```

2. how print, in a human readable form, the type of an object?

C++ make available an operator, [`typeid()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid), that return an object of a class, [`std::type_info`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info), with, among other things, a [`name()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) method that return a C-style string description of the type.

So you can write

```
std::pair x{1, 2.0};

std::cout << typeid(x).name() << '\n';
```

Unfortunately the description string is implementation specific and, for non trivial types, not really descriptive for a human being.

For example, from that code, I obtain

> ```
> St4pairIidE
> ```

from g++ and

> ```
> NSt3__14pairIidEE
> ```

from clang++.

Obviously, if you're interested in the template parameter deduced for the `std::pair`, you can deduce the single types (`int` and `double`) and print them.

For example, you can write a function as follows

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
void print_pair_types (std::pair<T1, T2> const &)
 {
   std::cout << "First pair type: " << typeid(T1).name() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Second pair type: " << typeid(T2).name() << std::endl;
 }
```

and call it with `x`

```
std::pair x{1, 2.0};

print_pair_types(x);
```

From both g++ and clang++ I obtain

> ```
> First pair type: i
> Second pair type: d
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The quickest and simplest method I've found so far to print the deduced type of anything at compile-time is to divide it by `nullptr`:

```cpp
#include <tuple>

int main() {
    auto a = std::make_tuple(0, 10ul, +[](int&&) -> int { return 42; });
    a / nullptr;
}
```

GCC's output looks like this:

```
 In function 'int main()':
5:7: error: no match for 'operator/' (operand types are 'std::tuple<int, long unsigned int, int (*)(int&&)>' and 'std::nullptr_t')
```